# Accepting an answer although I did not understand the solution, is it ok?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I sometimes have lost interest in the question or do not want to think through every Detail of an answer of somebody. Since I don't want to be rude I accept an answer so other People do not waste their time. Is there a better way to deal with those situations?

Comment: The title says you don't understand the solution; the body says you have lost interest in the question. These are two very different things. Which one do you actually mean to ask about?

Comment: Well it's sometimes connected I usually hope for a solution that I understand Right away but then I get a solution which requires some knowledge I don't have. Often it is a Problem that is if you have advanced understanding it is easy to solve. But since I don't have those prerequisits there is often some kind of trick involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting is *not* mandatory. If the answer isn't helpful because you don't understand, then I hope you don't accept it, but instead, comment asking for more clarification (as long as it's within the scope of the answer. If it starts to get tangential, then posting a follow-up question is the recommended way)

From [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

Also, from [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. *It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally*.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: From now on I will leave the Questions unaccepted then. About follow-up Questions however I did this a couple times but there is usually a commentor who tells me that I have already asked a similiar Question.

Comment: @RM777 It's not clear you've tried leaving a comment to the answer. With me at least several times, & I've seen it happen in other cases, the OP asks for clarification. With myself & at least a fairly large majority of other cases, the answerer responds to try to ensure it's understood. As far as I know, this was fully resolved for my answers, plus also for most other cases. However, if this doesn't work & you ask a new question, make sure you reference the original question & only ask about what you're unsure of. I've seen this done successfully a few times, even with somebody else asking!